# what is the number used by apple geolocation

Tags: geolocation

Whenever we use the geolocation api we get a number like 3.234345 for latitude and longitude which basically describes our position.

Is the number in radians ? what exactly is this number and what does it mean.

Sorry I tried searching a lot of places but could not find an answer,
Would appreciate it if some one can help me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It is called Decimal Degrees and is used by Apple , Google maps etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees